# How to separate two series by displaying Line between them in Column chart C#?

Tags: c#, charts

I have 2 series (2016 and 2017) in column chart and all datapoints values are showing fine. but I need to differentiate two series values by showing thick border line between two series.

because , now it seems to combining the 2017 values with 2016 series values since no separator line not there.

FYI.

[image: Current Column Chart Image]

EDIT:
 After used vertical line in my column chart the output as like below,

[image]

But i need only one Line that should present between the two series .

how do i remove other lines.

Finally , Got the expected Output.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cn use a StripLine, a VerticalLineAnnotation or draw the line in the PostPaint event.

Comment: @TaW,  As i displayed in my image , I need to differentiate the two series, so i need to show the strip line after first series END. how can i do the same? Help appreciated

Comment: if anyone knows answer, Please update the same.  Help Appreciated.

Comment: Got the answer. thanks for all your comments. Code snippet :                                            var series = Mainchart.Series[0]; //series object
                var chartArea = Mainchart.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea];
                chartArea.AxisX.StripLines.Add(new StripLine
                {
                    BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid,
                    BorderColor = Color.Black,
                    Interval = 0,
                    IntervalOffset = 1.5,
                    IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Years
                });

Answer (score 2):

```
var series = Mainchart.Series[0]; //series object
                var chartArea = Mainchart.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea];
                chartArea.AxisX.StripLines.Add(new StripLine
                {
                    BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid,
                    BorderColor = Color.Black,
                    Interval = 0, // to show only one vertical line
                    IntervalOffset = 1.5, // for showing Vertical line between 2 series 
                    IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Years // for me years
                });
```

Comment: Is that a working solution?? It doesn't relate to the last DataPoint in the 1st Series, does it??

Comment: yes, for my case it works fine. see my third image final output

Answer (score 1):

You may use StripLine:

```
StripLine limit_lower_strip = new StripLine();
limit_lower_strip.Interval = 0;
limit_lower_strip.IntervalOffset = v1_lower;
limit_lower_strip.StripWidth = 0.0;
limit_lower_strip.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Red);
limit_lower_strip.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
limit_lower_strip.BorderWidth = 5;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Add(limit_lower_strip);
```

Comment: StripLine is a good idea. Can you add a screenshot to show the effect?

Comment: An example: [Win Form Charting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503043/win-form-charting)

Comment: @user30,  Will it add all the XAxis or peritculer position, If so As i displayed in my image , I need to differentiate the two series, so i need to show the strip line after first series END.  how can i do the same? Help appreciated.

Comment: @user3060520.  I have tried the same but nothing happened.  No lines and nothing.

Comment: Did you add points?  For example: // Declare new random variable
            Random rand = new Random();

            // Add  data
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
            {
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i), rand.Next(20,35));
            } [Further example @ MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.stripline(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If it is hard, instead use a Vertical Line [C# Line Chart How to Create Vertical Line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801257/c-sharp-line-chart-how-to-create-vertical-line)

Comment: @user3060520, Thanks for your reply,  I have tried the  vertical line drawing and its displaying for every interval but i need to show only between two series.  help most welcome!  See my questions for the updated image.